# Is the data from an accelerometer more accurate when retrieved from a native API?

Tags: java, c, accelerometer

A friend and I are developing an application that reads data from the accelerometer to process it later. We are working with a Blackberry Playbook (Android based).

We need the most accurate data possible. He says the readings he gets from the Playbook's accelerometer are more accurate when done with a native C API, when compared to the readings obtained from the Java API. I thought that maybe the rate at which he is reading the data from each API is making him think that the C code readings are more accurate.

The reading rate is set and the data is read in C like this:

```
/* 25000 microseconds  = 25 miliseconds */
static const int ACCELEROMETER_RATE = 25000;

sensor_set_rate(SENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, ACCELEROMETER_RATE);
sensor_set_skip_duplicates(SENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, true);

/* ...code ommited... */

/* gets the data */
sensor_event_get_xyz(event, &force_x, &force_y, &force_z);
```

And in Java like this:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

/* ...code ommited... */

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    return;

mSensorX = event.values[0];
mSensorY = event.values[1];
mSensorZ = event.values[2];
}
```

I've read before that SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI` sets the reading rate to approximately 20ms, but I'm not sure.

Does it make sense that these the code in C will get more accurate data than the code in Java?

Comment: what do you (or your friend) mean 'more accurate'?How do you know the real value?Do you mean it prints more digits?

Comment: @byrondrossos According to what he wants, more accurate means that the  data doesn't change much when the device is in a stationary position, i.e. if the device is laying on a table, the (x, y, z) readings from the accelerometer should not change like crazy, as it happens with some devices.

Comment: If sensor jitter is a problem, you need to handle it yourself unless the driver can do it for you. In the C code, the call to `sensor_set_skip_duplicates` might change something that the Java code does not have access to.

Answer (score 1):

The Blackberry developers are probably using the library containing the c code in the Java implementation too.

No, the language should play no role whatsoever, since both c and java are reduced to bytecode anyway.

Comment: I'd say there is quite a difference between C and Java binaries since the Java binary runs in the JVM and the C binary does not.

Comment: @honkytonk true, but my point here is that they have access to the exact same resources, even using the same driver and probably system calls(I do not know how deeply buried into the os the JVM is.)The JVM code translates java bytecode to machine instructions anyway:)

Comment: The Java code is limited to what the interface it works with offers. If the native glue code that interfaces with the device, for example, does not offer methods to affect jitter handling, the Java code would get different signals than the C code. The bridge from the JVM to native always limits the possibilities in the Java code.